# PHP form: check if user input matches values in .txt file

Tags: php, forms, text, user-input

I have a PHP form with 2 user inputs, 1 user select, a clear button and submit button:

- Input box for Student Name
- Input box for Student Number
- Drop down list with 4 available courses with the course name and
  course code

I have **courses.txt** that stores the 4 available courses with the course name, course code and the maximum number of people who can enrol:

- Animation Film Design:AFD-250:6
- Digital Sculpture:DS-410:4
- History of Animation:HA-240:6
- Visual Effects:VE-298:4

I have **student.txt** that stores the current list of student names and their student number:

- Riley Anderson:PX-06-009
- Tinker Bell:DY-43-200
- Carl Fredricksen:PX-45-767
- Edith Gru:DW-21-492
- Mad Hatter:DY-03-195
- Buzz Lightyear:PX-34-121
- Stuart Little:CP-17-199
- Bob Minion:DW-34-628
- Thomas O'Malley:DY-21-987
- Kitty Softpaws:DW-07-201
- James Sullivan:PX-01-111
- Mike Wazowski:PX-68-524
- Sheriff Woodie:PX-32-597

I am working on having the user input checked after Submit is pressed to ensure the Student Name and Student Number match an existing record in student.txt and the course selected is an existing course in courses.txt and the maximum enrolment number has not been reached.

If the student name or student number does not match an existing record the student must not be told which part of the student information does not match.

If the student name and student number match one of the records in student.txt and if the course selected has not reached maximum enrolment and if the student has not enrolled in the course already, the student can be enrolled into the course.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Registration Form</title>
    <style>
        body{background-color: #ffffe6; width:610px;}
        h1 {color: #29a3a3;}
        .inputbox {padding: 7px; border: #FF9966 1px solid; border-radius: 4px;}
        .btn {padding: 10px; background-color: #29a3a3; border: solid 1px #FF9966; border-radius: 4px; color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: bolder; cursor: pointer;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
// Sanitization and Validation coding will go here


// Define and set variables
$studentname = "";
$studentnumber = "";
$courses = " ";
$datafile = "student.txt";
$in = fopen ('courses.txt', 'r') or die ("courses.txt cannot be opened for reading.");


// Check to see if input of $studentname matches a name in student.txt
if (isset ($_POST['student.txt'])) {
    $studentname = htmlentities ($_POST['student.txt']);
    $DB = fopen ($datafile, 'r') or die ("$datafile cannot be opened for reading.");

    $found = FALSE;
    while ($record = fgets ($DB) and ! $found) {
       $field = explode (":", htmlentities (trim ($record)));
       $found = $studentname === $field[0];
    }

    fclose ($DB);

    if ($found) {
       echo "<p>$field[0] $field[1].</p>\n";
    }
 }

$DB = fopen ($datafile, 'r') or die ("$datafile cannot be opened for reading.");
 while ($record = fgets ($DB) ) {
    $field = explode (":", htmlentities (trim ($record)));
    //echo "   <option value=\"$field[1]\">$field[0] $field[1]</option>\n";
 }
 fclose ($DB);
 

 


?>

<h1>Course Registration</h1>
<form method="post" action="index.php">
    <fieldset><legend><strong>Student Information</strong></legend>
        <dl>
            <dt>Student Name:</dt>
            <dd><input class="inputbox" name="studentname" type="text" id="studentname" value="<?php echo $studentname;?>" required autofocus placeholder="Please enter your first and last name" tabindex="10" size="50"></dd>
            <br>
            <br>
            <dt>Student Number:</dt>
            <dd><input class="inputbox" name="studentnumber" type="text" id="studentnumber" value="<?php echo $studentnumber;?>" required placeholder="Please enter using the following format: PX-03-046" tabindex="20" size="50"></dd>
        </dl>
        <br>
    </fieldset>
    <br>
    <fieldset><legend><strong>Course Selection</strong></legend>
        <br>
        Select a Course:<select name="courses" tabindex="30">\n";
            <option value="-1" >Available Courses...</option>
                <?php
                while(($fields = fgetcsv($in, null, ':')) != false) {
                    if (count($fields) > 1) {
                        echo "
                            <option value=\"$fields[1]\">$fields[0] $fields[1]</option>";
                    }
                }
                ?>
        </select>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
    </fieldset>
    <div>
        <p>
            <input name="reset" type="reset" tabindex="40" value="Clear Form" class="btn">
            <input name="submit" type="submit" tabindex="50" value="Submit Form" class="btn">
        </p>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it is time to start using a real database

Comment: Yeah, you are using text files to store data... you're going to make life needlessly more difficult for yourself. Just use a simple database. Also, you may want to look into some design patterns for separation of concerns..your code will get really messy in a bit. I made a simple starter MVC framework that you may find useful: https://github.com/LansanaCamara/php-mvc

Comment: Hi, at this time I have to use the text files.  I think the next go'round will incorporate MySQL.